# Problem while fetching values using foreign key

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables.

**Table 1 :** `t_atc_list`

```
id | a_name | s_title | r_name
------------------------------
80 | ss     | 128     | 5
```

Where s_title & r_name is foreign key.

**Table 2 :** `t_s_list`

```
s_id | title
-------------
128  | Song Title
```

**Table 3 :** `t_r_list`

```
r_id | r_name
--------------
5    | Artist
```

I have used following query to have desired output in this format `Song Title- Artist` using album name that is a_name

```
$resultid=mysql_query("SELECT s_title, r_name FROM t_atc_list where a_name='$album' ");
$rowid=mysql_fetch_array($resultid);
$query=mysql_query("SELECT s.title, r.r_name FROM t_a_list as a, t_r_list as r, WHERE s.s_id=$rowid('s_title') and r.r_id= $rowid('r_name')");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

Comment: Why did you put the song title into a separate table?

Comment: I don't want to put anything anywhere. I want to show the values from song table and artist table.

Comment: yeah I understood the question just wanted to mention that it doesn't look a good db schema to me.

Comment: t_atc_list is playlist... that I have stored using all fields primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the SQL query you want is:

```
SELECT 
    t.id,
    t.a_name,
    s.title as s_title,
    r.r_name
FROM
    t_atc_list t
        INNER JOIN t_s_list s ON t.s_title = s.s_id
        INNER JOIN t_r_list r ON t.r_name = r.r_id
WHERE
    t.a_name = '$album'
```

FWIW, your table naming conventions and your schema in general are pretty wacky. At the very least, what's wrong with "tracks", "songs" and "artists", or whatever they are supposed to be (or for purists, "track", "song", "artist") for your table names?

Comment: Ya its correct, retrieving values `artists` but giving blank for song title.. NO Issue I will modify it.... Can u please elaborate it. I am new with this...

Answer (score 0):

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT s.title, r.r_name 
FROM t_a_list a, t_r_list r, WHERE s.s_id={$rowid['s_title']} 
and r.r_id={$rowid['r_name']}");
```

you are misusing $rowid in the string. I don't know if it's THE problem but it certainly is one.

PS: you could rewrite the queries into one join-query. but before you delve into SQL, I suggest you get the PHP basics straight and read about [arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in....